# What is an efficient if/else in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to return a different value using a simple if/else to check for an even number in Java.

```
if (move % 2 == 0) {
    return "o";
} else {
    return "O";
}
```

I know in JavaScript you can use

```
if () : a ? b ;
```

Can this be used in Java?

Comment: `if` and `else` are pretty damn efficient...

Comment: ternary: `return (move % 2 == 0) ? "o" : "O";` - but it's equivalent to yours, but can be useful for very short `if-else` statements for brevity. (this was edited)

Comment: Can't you also do: `return (move % 2 == 0) ? "o" : "O";`

Comment: @birryree: That is not a valid statement. You meant to say: `return (move % 2 == 0) ? "o" : "O";`

Comment: Whoops, thanks @Shakedown - edited in place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use the ternary operator in Java:

```
return (move % 2 == 0) ? "o" : "O";
```

**Just don't expect it to be any faster than the `if`-`else`.**

Comment: I just wanted to reduce a few lines of code. Thanks for all of the responses.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the [conditional operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25) in Java:

```
return (move % 2 == 0) ? "o": "O";
```

It won't make your program any faster, but it's a little more concise and if you are familiar with the conditional operator, you will probably find it easier to read.

But conversely, if you *don't* know this operator it will be hard to guess what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. It's called a [ternary operator](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/ternary.html)

Usage:

```
  true ? case1 : case2;              // returns case1
  false ? case1 : case2;             // returns case2
```

Comment: That's a pretty bad example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "optimizing" the `if` versus the ternary operator `?` you should focus on the `move % 2 == 0`. If `move` is an integer and not a floating point variable this *may* be faster:

```
if( move & 1 == 0 )
    return "E";
else
    return "O";
```

Bit operations are usually faster than division or modulo calculations.

Answer (score 0):

`(conditional) ? if-true-statement : if-false-statement;`

Yes it can, check out the Wikipedia page for [Ternary Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can use an if-statement in a more or less efficient way.

... and further more - keep in mind that, and this does not only apply for if-statements:

You should **never** try to optimize expressions used, for performance reasons - write code that focuses on readability (and in term, maintainability). The reason for this is that there's a JIT (Just-in-time compiler) that will optimize the bytecode, and modify the instructions you've specified in your byte-code.

If you're thinking about using the ternary operator, then consider, will this lead to harder to understand code (if you're multiple people working on the code). If it's just you working on the code then do as you please - and yes:

```
Object var = boolean-expression ? some-value : another-value;
```

is much more compact than:

```
Object var;
if (boolean-expression)
   var = some-value;
else
   var = another-value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this to be blindingly fast, which is pretty dubious, you should also consider a lookup table:

```
static final char[] moveChar = {"o", "O"};
// ...
return moveChar[move % 2];
```

But I wouldn't implement any of the suggestions given here without timing them, and I wouldn't do anything at all until it had been proven that what you have now is really a bottleneck, by which I mean that it consumes more than about 50% of the CPU time.